# Why is same task created again?

Tags: ruby

Below in an excerpt of code I have written to interface with an API (Habitica). The below code aims to create a task, unless a task of the same name already exists. However, in practice it will continue to create a task of the same name over and over (although the task has already been successfully added to the task list). When I restart this program & repeat, it then knows the task is already there.

```
def task_exists?(text)
    @habit.tasks.todos.any? { |t| t.text == text }
end

# create task
def create_task(text)
  if task_exists?(text)
    puts "\nTask already exists. No action taken!"
  else
    puts "\nCreating #{text}..."
    @habit.tasks.create(
    text: text,
    type: 'todo'
    )
  end
end
```

Could this be due to the flow of logic in my code - i.e. is something obvious reventing the method from seeing the updated task list or can I ensure that the "updated" list is searched without needing to restart the program?

Thanks.

Comment: How is `todos` defined?

Comment: Could be caching – if `@habit` (or `@habit.tasks` or `@habit.tasks.todos`) is being cached somewhere, ensure that you have refreshed the cache, either when adding a new task or while checking if the task exists.

Comment: It is most certainly caching. How are `@habit.tasks` and `@habit.tasks.todo` defined?

Comment: `@habit` is a global variable for credentials to connect to the API.

`@habit = HabiticaClient.new(ENV['HABITICA_USER_ID'], ENV['HABITICA_API_TOKEN'])`
```

`@habit.tasks` and  `@habit.tasks.todo` are handled by the API that I'm trying to connect my script to: https://github.com/wwqrd/habitica_client... perhaps the issue lies here

Comment: @omnikron You should post that as an answer.